# fantasy and reality sayings

Tags: quotes, popular-refrains, proverbs

- You should never act out a fantasy because the reality never matches up.

Is this a famous saying (especially about sexual fantasies)? Or is there any sayings or quotes similar to this?

I read this in a novel in which a woman says “They say you should never act out a fantasy because the reality never matches up.” As this woman often uses word plays or parodies of famous phrases, I am interested in whether this sentence is also some kind of parody.

Thank you for your kind assistance!

Answer (score 1):

OP asks "Are there any sayings or quotes similar to this?"
A similar saying ([see ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317925/is-the-expression-never-meet-your-heroes-an-adage)) is

> Never meet your heroes (because they're sure to disappoint you).

Somewhat similar, from Aesop's Fables ([see ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26850/be-careful-what-you-wish-for)) is

> Be careful what you wish for (because it might be a liability).

Comment: Yes. the notion that fantasies are disappointing when turned into reality is such a commonplace idea that it can be found in many sayings and proverbs. It is a "common sense" idea.